# "the application has stopped unexpectedly please try again"

Tags: android

I am facing this problem. when I want to run a simple application on the simulator I am getting this message `the application has stopped unexpectedly please try again emulator android`.

I have already tried:

> 1. delete all my AVD and create a new one.
> 2. click the back button and run it from eclipse.
> 3. I have checked my manifest file and it seems all fine.

could anyone give me any solution ?
I have attached the following sources:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.notesquirrel;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public  static final String DEBUGTAG = "SS";
public  static final String TEXTFILE= "NoteSquirrel.txt";
@Override
//this method is called whenever the application is started for the first time

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //display the xml activity_main
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addSaveButtonListener();
    try {
        loadSaveFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void loadSaveFile() throws IOException{
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = openFileInput(TEXTFILE);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            new DataInputStream(fis) ) );
    
    String line;
    while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
        editText.append(line);
        editText.append("\n");
    }
    fis.close();
}
private void addSaveButtonListener(){
    Button saveBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
    //onClickListener is an interface 
    saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        //this code will run whenever the button is clicked. 
        public void onClick(View v) {
            
            //we need to cast it to EditText
            
            EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d(DEBUGTAG, "Save Button clicked");
            //we get the text from it 
            String text = editText.getText().toString();
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(TEXTFILE, MODE_PRIVATE);
                fos.write(text.getBytes());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d (DEBUGTAG, "Unable to save file ");
            
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

AndroidManifest.java

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.notesquirrel.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

LogCat:

```
04-26 18:41:22.968: W/System.err(363): java.io.FileNotFoundException:             /data/data/com.example.notesquirrel/files/NoteSquirrel.txt (No such file or directory)
04-26 18:41:22.968: W/System.err(363):  at      org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(Native Method)
04-26 18:41:22.978: W/System.err(363):  at     dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.open(BlockGuard.java:232)
04-26 18:41:22.978: W/System.err(363):  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:80)
04-26 18:41:22.978: W/System.err(363):  at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileInput(ContextImpl.java:404)
04-26 18:41:22.978: W/System.err(363):  at   android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput(ContextWrapper.java:152)
04-26 18:41:22.978: W/System.err(363):  at com.example.notesquirrel.MainActivity.loadSaveFile(MainActivity.java:43)
04-26 18:41:22.978: W/System.err(363):  at com.example.notesquirrel.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
04-26 18:41:22.978: W/System.err(363):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-26 18:41:22.978: W/System.err(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
04-26 18:41:22.978: W/System.err(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-26 18:41:22.988: W/System.err(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-26 18:41:22.988: W/System.err(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-26 18:41:22.988: W/System.err(363):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-26 18:41:22.988: W/System.err(363):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-26 18:41:22.988: W/System.err(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-26 18:41:22.988: W/System.err(363):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-26 18:41:22.988: W/System.err(363):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-26 18:41:22.988: W/System.err(363):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-26 18:41:22.998: W/System.err(363):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-26 18:41:22.998: W/System.err(363):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-26 18:41:22.998: D/AndroidRuntime(363): Shutting down VM
04-26 18:41:22.998: W/dalvikvm(363): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
04-26 18:41:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(363): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-26 18:41:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(363): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  activity ComponentInfo{com.example.notesquirrel/com.example.notesquirrel.MainActivity}:  java.lang.NullPointerException
04-26 18:41:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
04-26 18:41:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-26 18:41:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-26 18:41:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-26 18:41:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-26 18:41:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-26 18:41:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-26 18:41:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-26 18:41:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-26 18:41:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-26 18:41:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-26 18:41:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-26 18:41:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(363): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-26 18:41:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at java.io.FilterInputStream.available(FilterInputStream.java:54)
04-26 18:41:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:245)
04-26 18:41:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at java.io.BufferedReader.fillBuf(BufferedReader.java:128)
04-26 18:41:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:357)
04-26 18:41:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at com.example.notesquirrel.MainActivity.loadSaveFile(MainActivity.java:54)
04-26 18:41:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at com.example.notesquirrel.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
04-26 18:41:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-26 18:41:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
04-26 18:41:23.008: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: see the logcat stacktrace for uncaught exception or place it here

Comment: Add logcat stacktrace.

Comment: Encapsul all tour main code by  try catch to see eventual exception

Comment: is the problem when you click a button?

Comment: whenever I try to run it directly from eclipse or from the simulator  when I click the icon of the app..the problem occurs..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you see in exception msg, your file is not exists. You should handle it in right way, check that file exists and after that create it or open depending on file existance. In `loadSaveFile()` after `openFileInput` `fis` still `null`

Comment: I see that you are right. the problem is with the file. but what's wrong with my code? I was writing the lines from an EditText  into a file, and then I wanted to read it when the app is loading again...

Comment: @Shiran, 'openFileInput' is not creating file if it doesn't exists but 'openFileOutput' does. See docs for those methods in [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput(java.lang.String))